# Return value from recursive method java

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

Got two methods:

```
public void getBalance(){
    balance(root);
}

private void balance(TreeNode node) {


    if (node != null && node.left != null) {
        balance(node.left);
        balance(node.right);
        System.out.println(node.left);
        //sout work fine
    }
}
```

need to return value from balance();

if I change return value from void to TreeNode, and change code

```
    private TreeNode balance(TreeNode node) {


    if (node != null && node.left != null) {
        balance(node.left);
        balance(node.right);
        return node.left;

    }
    return balance(node);
}
```

return sStackOverflowError Exception.

I need to return `node left` from this method.

Please help.

Comment: what do you expect if `node` is null or `node.left` is null?

Comment: also: how do you expect a method with return type void to return anything?

Comment: If `node` is `null`, you keep on invoking `balance` recursively - that's *likely* the reason for your `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: node.left is not null, and IF change return value from void to TreeNode, method return StackOverflowError Exception.

Comment: `node.left`may not be null, but one of its linked node or subnode is null. So, what do you expect to get if `node` is null or `node.left` is null?

Comment: you may have many node left, so which node left do you want? the low level or high level?

Comment: root node do not have link to high level nodes, and I pass root element which does not have high nodes.

Comment: `root` node has a `left` node and a `right` node. Calling balance of root node, call balance on those too

Comment: you can avoid stack overflow changing your design and use while instead of recursive method. you can find a general design pattern to do it in this: http://www.jndanial.com/73